# Website works on localhost but freezes when deployed to vercel/netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, netlify, vercel

I made a react blog that uses threejs, react-three-fiber and some react effects like Typing effect. It works great on localhost but freezes when deployed to vercel/netlify.

This is the localhost and the wireframe mesh from threejs is rendered as well as the typing effect.

[image: localhost deployment]

When deployed to vercel/netlify, no mesh is rendered and even the navigation tabs are not working.

This is my [repository](https://github.com/0xDexe/Blog).

I cant understand why this is happening, my code works fine. Can someone please help? It would mean a lot.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the app crash if you run the production build locally with `next build && next start`? And are there any errors in the browser console on production? If so can you add them to the question?

Comment: no it doesn't crash, and there are literally no errors. It just doesn't render

Comment: What do you get back from your GET request? Is there any sort of HTML returned?
I've not used the libraries you're using but one idea might be to dynamically import everything inside your index page, as the server-side rendering might be mucking up your `Back` component. I've had similar issues with apis that access the DOM or use canvases.

Comment: What did the issue end up being?